# Why does Setvisibility() not work in custom view?

Tags: android, visibility, custom-component

I have a layout like this

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignParentTop ="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Login" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:visibility="gone" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEditUser"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtLoggedInfo"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:text="Edit User" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my custom view is

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout {

    private Context context = null;
    private TextView txtLoggedInfo;
    private View contentView = null;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        getLayout();
    }

    private void getLayout() {


        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        contentView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        this.addView(contentView);

                //......

        if (bool ) {
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        } else {

            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout))
                    .setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    }
```

I want to  Start a new activity when click on Login button and go back to MyView after login.I used

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layputParams = new Relative.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
this.addContentView(new MyView(this), layputParams);
```

inside the activity for go back to the activity. When doing like this, the view visibility does not change.What is the problem here and how can i fix that problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would strongly suggest you to to do this

```
  @Override
  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
 if (bool ) {
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    } else {

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout))
                .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

that means that if windows focus has changed, all the content has been created. In your previous code, there is a possibility that condition did not work because all the content has not been loaded yet.

Comment: Then how to add contentView?.This shows NullPointerException because window focused before getLayout() called.

Comment: I need to show/hide views inside MyView. and go to this view from the activity

Comment: where did you override the onWindowsFocusChanged()?